# How to disable wheel zoom in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to disable wheel zoom in, zoom out for both x and y axis. Or zoom in to be simultaneously for both x and y axis?

I am using the following code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
p.circle(x=0, y=0, radius=50,
      fill_color="yellow",line_color = 'black', alpha=0.6)
p.circle(-25,25, radius=5, color="black", alpha=0.8)
p.circle(25,25, radius=5, color="black", alpha=0.8)
show(p)
```

Zooming in and out the 'eyes' are not constantly in the same place relative to the 'face'. Any idea to overpass that?
Image:
[image]

Comment: See: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#specifying-tools

Answer (score 6):

You can specify list of tools, and not include `wheel_zoom`:

```
p = figure(title='Title of my plot',
           ...,
           tools="pan,box_zoom,reset,resize,save")
```

Works for 0.10.0.  See docs [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/tools.html).

Comment: I think Mpizos does want the `wheel_zoom` tool, but he doesn't want the functionality of only zooming the x dimension when the rolling the wheel over the x axis

Answer (score 1):

I'm creating a stackoverflow account to share my experience dealing with what I think is the same issue, in case anyone else still wonders about this in 2021. There is a full, simple solution here.

As of 2018, it seems that Bokeh has introduced an attribute to the WheelZoomTool that controls this behavior. Here's a short example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import WheelZoomTool

TOOLS = "tap,pan"
p = figure(
    title='My Figure',
    tools=TOOLS
)
p.add_tools(WheelZoomTool(zoom_on_axis=False))
p.axis.visible = False
```

Bokeh documentation: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.WheelZoomTool.zoom_on_axis

Answer (score -3):

With zooming you need a camera.
All of your objects is subtracted with the camera's (x,y) position.
Then you must have a zoom variable. That variable must be > 0.

```
 resPosX = objectX - camera * cameraZoomFactor
```

(+ you need to multiply with the radius of the circle)